# Strategies for scale a nodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have an app in NodeJS.

Recently we have been getting a lot more traffic (this is a new experience for me) and so I have been running into the "EMFILE: too many open files" error that is caused when a single process tries to open more files than the filesystem allows.

I have increased this limit, so we are good for now.  However I'm not sure how long this solution will last...

I am wondering:  What are other commonly used options for scaling a Node Application that is getting increasing amounts of traffic?  (specifically with a mind to the open files limit problem.)

The PM2 process manager which allows clustering catches my eye (am I correct in understanding that every instance of the application requires it's own core -- ie you can't run 4 instances on a single core?).  Are there any other techniques that are regularly used?

Thanks (in advance)

Comment: You could try increasing the amount of max files that can be opened [see this issue](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/962#issuecomment-71680663).

Answer (score 0):

PM2 is a simple solution when you want to run more than one instance of Node, another common alternative is the cluster module http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html  Keep in mind, that you will need to configure another http server such as Nginx to reverse proxy your user requests to your Node processes.

You can run any number of Node processes, regardless of the amount of cores. But since each node process is a single thread, and each core can execute a single thread a time, the optimal configuration is when the number of cores match the number of Node processes. If the number of Node processes is greater than the number of cores, under load, you will experience reduced performance due to redundant context switches your processor will have to perform.

Comment: pm2 is using the cluster module if you want it too ;) `pm2 start app.js -i 0`